# Rich Text Field not returning desired output

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor rich text field for my Django blog app. But not getting the desired output. If I write some heading text, on the front end the output is `<h1> Hello </h1>`. But I don't want heading tags, I also tried to **striptags** but in that case, the output is not heading it is simple paragraph text

index.html

```
{% for posts in post %}
   <div>{{posts.content|striptags}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Rich text model

```
content = RichTextField(blank = True ,null = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want the `safe` filter, which tells django you know you are doing something a little bit dangerous, and it should not try to protect you.

```
{% posts.content|safe %}
```

that will actually render the html (including any malicious javascript a user may have entered (ie i would strongly recomend using a package like `bleach` or `html-sanitizer` to only allow specific html tags)